# Google analytics finding most popular pages

Tags: google-analytics

I have a couple domains under one GA account. I have a set of pages setup like:

domain1.com/listing/{UNIQUE ID}
domain2.com/listing/{UNIQUE ID}

Unique ID is a dynamic listing id. How can I run a report to find out the most popular listing for the last month? I am sort of new to GA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be create a custom report and configure like this:

[image]

where you capture the page and its pageviews (optionally with unique pageviews), and also you would need to set a filter on the page to capture only those within the domain1.com/listing/ and domain2.com/listing/ folders. Also, you would need to be capturing the hostname, too, which is a good idea since you have two domains coming into the same property.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow @nyuen guide. But, you can also use Google Webmaster Tools(GWT) to find out popular pages easily.

First go [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?hl=en) and click on associate properties to link your GWT to analytics

Then you can access [search analytic](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-analytics) directly from webmaster tools, like this.

[image: Search Analytic From Google Webmaster Tools]

**Google Webmaster show most significant hits, while Analytic show all traffic source including fake bot traffic. So GWT will show you actual popular pages compare to Google Analytic**